# some process is overwriting my .zshrc config file

Tags: gnu-screen

i want to customize my dynamic title on gnu screen

i used to have a script that worked on my previous distribution (mint), but now that i moved to lubuntu 18.04 it doesn't work anymore

it's placed in my **~/.zshrc** file, with a **precmd()** function that prompt the sequence needed by gnu screen to set the dynamic titles (lets say the current directory plus another information) :

```
precmd () {
  if [[ $TERM == screen* ]]; then
    print -Pn '\ek%~ INFO\e\\'
  fi
}
```

this used to work, but not anymore. But i still have the dynamics titles working, it's just not coming from my script (i noticed because of the disparition of the INFO part), i can delete it from **~/.zshrc** file without any impact

So it's coming from elsewhere, and it's overwriting my script. But if i call the action of a **title()** function, in my **~/.zshrc** file, suddenly i can overwrite the action :

```
title () {
  if [[ $TERM == screen* ]]; then
    print -Pn '\ek%~ INFO\e\\'
  fi
}
precmd () {
  title
}
```

well, actually not exactly, i don't need to call the **title()** function in a **precmd()** function, wich is ignored anyway, if i erase the **precmd()** function it works the same, as long as i name my function **title()**

so what's going on here ? how is the "hidden" **precmd()** function overwriting my prompt, but i can overwrite some **tilte()** function ? I don't understand what is going on ?

i looked into the **/etc/zsh** folder, there are no **title()** or **precmd()** function there

Comment: I don't have the answer for you, but you're going to want to specify *which* Lubuntu you're using. 18.04 was the last LXDE version and there were many **drastic** changes made after that as the project moved to LXQt. They're still both currently supported, so you could reasonably have either one. The answer to your question quite likely hinges on knowing which version you're using.

Comment: @KGIII you're right, i edited it (i'm using 18.04)

Comment: I checked back to see if you got an answer. You did not. You may have better luck asking [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/).

Comment: good idea, i will then !